# Keras ImageDataGenerator doesn't work properly with shuffle

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I have created two ImageDataGenerator objects to process two images at the same time (one image and his mask) to train an autoencoder/u-net. To randomize the dataset I set `shuffle=True`. I take these images from two folders (one for the image and other for the mask), so I use two `flow_from_directory` with the same seed. However, in practice that doesn't work and the mask extracted doesn't correspond to the extracted image. Both images (image and mask) have the same file name.

Here is the code I have:

```
data_gen_args = dict(rescale = 1./255,
                     rotation_range = 5,
                    zoom_range = 0.05,
                    horizontal_flip = True)
image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

seed = 1

image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train_'+str(shape),
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    class_mode = None,
    batch_size = batch_size,
    shuffle = True,
    seed = seed)

mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train_mask_'+str(shape),
    color_mode = 'grayscale',
    class_mode = None,
    batch_size = batch_size,
    shuffle = True,
    seed = seed)
```

Any idea on what's wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not find where the shuffle function is used in flow_from_drectory(). Are your filenames and subdirectories names in 'data/train_'+str(shape) and in 'data/train_mask_'+str(shape) the same? I think this could explain the uncorrelated outputs

Comment: Yes, the filenames are the same in both directories.

Comment: I have made some test and both folders have the same number of files and these files have the same name in both folders. However, the filenames are read in a different order when using _os.rename()_.

Comment: That was the problem. Filenames in both directories are read in different order. To solve this, I have forced both lists to be sorted in the __init__ function of the _DictionaryIterator_ from the _image_ file in _preprocessing/image_